# How to handle gmail popup? See screenshot

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gmail

How to handle Gmail popup? See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Hi Aditya, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you elaborate on your question as currently, it is unclear what you want to achieve? What is the current behavior and what would you like it to be. Thanks

Comment: Click "Leave" ...

Comment: Maybe try to turn off Javascript. This should help

Comment: I have create a script for send mail and after that logout, but after running send mail script its showing popup. There is no way to find element for that popup. only this popup buttons work that time.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want to achieve, as the other comment requested.

Comment: See after sending mail i want logout and that script working fine, but some times this popup appeared, I just want to handle this popup.

Comment: I can't test it thoroughly, but I'd recommend trying a userscript that runs on `document-start` that makes `window.onbeforeunload` unwritable, and intercepts and discards `addEventListener` calls that try to attach to `beforeunload`.

Answer (score 0):

You may handle it by try-catch,

Sample Example:

You can call this method where you required, Else you can directly implement try-catch code where it throws.

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception Ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```